# How many memory barriers do we need to implement a Peterson lock?

Tags: c++, x86, mutex, memory-barriers

I'm trying to figure out how many memory fences do we need to implement a Peterson lock.   Clearly, we need at least one.

https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/

In practice, it seems that one is sufficient, based on a number of tests executed in different architectures.   However, in theory, do we need additional ones?

I have tried the code below

[my peterson_lock failed in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406311/my-peterson-lock-failed-in-this-situation)

changing the order between Mark A by Mark B and it works! However, the memory fence does not capture the ordering between Mark A and Mark B. So, does it mean that the program is still incorrect?

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
    volatile bool flag[2];
    volatile int victim;
} peterson_lock_t;

void peterson_lock_init(peterson_lock_t &lock) {
    lock.flag[0] = lock.flag[1] = false;
    lock.victim = 0;
}

void peterson_lock(peterson_lock_t &lock, int id) {
    lock.victim = id; // Mark as A
    lock.flag[id] = true; // Mark as B
    asm volatile ("mfence" : : : "memory");
    while (lock.flag[1 - id] && lock.victim == id);
}

void peterson_unlock(peterson_lock_t &lock, int id) {
    lock.flag[id] = false;
    lock.victim = id;
}
```

After replacing the order of lines "Mark as A" and "Mark as B" I expected the program to run almost always correctly, as it is now in agreement with the Wikipedia entry on Peterson lock.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm

However, the memory fence does not protect the ordering between Mark A and Mark B. Therefore, is it still possible that the program is incorrect? If so, how to fix it?

Comment: I'm curious about all possible scenarios: with global optimization and without it, inlined or not, Intel and non-Intel :)   However, I had in mind: global optimization, inlined and Intel

Comment: If your functions are inlined, of just with global optimization, I can say the code is broken without even trying to understand it. The mere fact that **you rely on volatile writes, alone**, simply doesn't provide any ordering: volatile is for expressing I/O, such as **all communication** with external devices, or async signals, which are essentially seen as external: you need to **use volatile everywhere or there is no ordering.** You can't set an ordinary variable then set a volatile flag to say "data ready" as only the 2nd is an I/O and ordered.

Comment: I am not a GCC inline asm expert, but AFAIK adding `asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");` around **all volatile data manipulations** is enough to order all "sections" of work in the compiled code.

Comment: but all variables here are volatile, right? where should I include the additional "volatile" flags?

Comment: Your whole program uses only volatile variables, for anything that might be shared between threads? I don't think so!

Comment: I'm assuming that pthread will be used in the remainder of the program

Comment: for the sake of simplicity, let us assume that indeed the program uses only volatile variables, for everything that might be shared among threads

Comment: Then my inline functions/global optimization comment obviously don't apply!

Comment: "_the memory fence does not protect the ordering between Mark A and Mark B_" No. **That** CPU always make stores visible in the exact order they are made in the asm code, and C/C++ memory semantics does not give the compiler the freedom to reorder volatile writes.

Comment: In peterson_lock, if processA sets lock.victim to 0, then immediately processB sets it to 1 (possible due to the vagaries of process scheduling), when will it ever get set back to 0?  When processB releases via peterson_unlock, it sets it to 1 again and processA is forever stuck in a loop.

Comment: @curiousguy: `volatile` + inline asm is a more or less valid way to roll your own atomics *for gcc/clang*.  The Linux kernel does that, and gcc at least tacitly / de-facto supports the Linux kernel.  The portable C11 way would be with `_Atomic` types and `memory_order_release` / `acquire` stores (because that's what volatile on x86 gives you, except that release-store also order non-atomic stores.)  This kind of ghetto way implicitly relying on x86 memory semantics (by leaving out no-op barriers) would make more sense written in actual asm, but at least it's clear enough.

Comment: @DanielS.: if you put `asm("" ::: "memory")` compiler barriers at the start/end of all your functions, it should behave as if the rest of your program used `volatile` everywhere.  i.e. block runtime reordering so your C program can take advantage of the x86 asm acq/rel runtime ordering.

Comment: @PeterCordes Tacitly until the next time they break the interpretation of `asm` annotations, or volatile, or null checking, or something else.

Comment: @PeterCordes `asm volatile(“”:::”memory”)` only blocks compiler reordering entirely. It doesn’t block OoO execution nor fences memory accesses.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: right, so it gives you behaviour that's as strong as the asm memory model of the target you're compiling for.  Which in this case is x86, giving you acq/rel ordering.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not so; Consider two nearby non-`volatile` memory accesses, `*a=x;` and `y=*b;`. In the absence of anything, a compiler is free to reorder them in program order: `mov y, [b]; mov [a], x;` (or not). Further, an OoO processor could even rereorder them back (or not). Placing `asm volatile("":::"memory")` forces the compiler to emit `mov [a], x; mov y, [b];` (source code order matches program text order), but there will be no fence instruction preventing an OoO processor from performing its own runtime reordering. For an explicit fence you need e.g. `asm volatile(“mfence”:::”memory”)`

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: `memory_order_acq_rel` ordering allows StoreLoad reordering, so we don't *need* to use expensive barriers to prevent it except in the one spot it matters *inside* the lock-taking function.  Nothing you've said is incompatible with my claim that `asm("" ::: "memory")` barriers at the start/end of your functions will effectively give you *`acq_rel`* ordering, not `seq_cst`.  Yes of course you still need a full barrier (`mfence` or a `lock`ed or serializing instruction) inside the lock-taking function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody uses a Peterson lock on mainstream platforms because mutexes are available.
But assuming you cannot use those and you are writing code for an old `X86` platform without access to modern primitives (no memory model, no mutexes, no atomic RMW operations), this algorithm might be considered.

Your implementation of the Peterson lock is incorrect (also after swapping the lines 'Mark as A' & 'Mark as B').
If you translate the Wikipedia pseudo code to `C++`, the correct implementation becomes:

```
typedef struct {
    volatile bool flag[2];
    volatile int victim;
} peterson_lock_t;

void peterson_lock(peterson_lock_t &lock, int id) {
    lock.flag[id] = true;
    lock.victim = 1-id;
    asm volatile ("mfence" ::: "memory"); // CPU #StoreLoad barrier
    while (lock.flag[1-id] && lock.victim == 1-id);
}

void peterson_unlock(peterson_lock_t &lock, int id) {
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory"); // compiler barrier
    lock.flag[id] = false;
}
```

In addition to the use of `volatile` on he `lock` variables, the `mfence` instruction (in `peterson_lock`) is necessary to prevent #StoreLoad reordering.
This shows a rare case where an algorithm requires sequential consistency; i.e. operations on the `lock` variables must take place in a single total order.

The use of `volatile` is based on non-portable (but 'almost' correct) properties on `gcc/X86`.
"'almost' correct" because even though a `volatile` store on `X86` is a release operation on CPU level, the compiler can still reorder operations on `volatile` and non-`volatile` data.
For that reason, I added a compiler barrier before resetting `lock.flag[id]` in `peterson_unlock`.

But it is probably a good idea to use `volatile` on all data that is shared between threads using this algorithm,
because the compiler can still perform store and load operations on non-`volatile` data in a CPU register only.

Note that with the use of `volatile` on shared data, the compiler barrier in `peterson_unlock` becomes redundant.

Comment: There's an `asm()` with a `"memory"` clobber in both your `lock` and `unlock` functions, so that's sufficient to protect non-`volatile` variables even if this inlines, just like a non-inline function call would.  Objects in memory need to have their object-representation in sync before such an asm statement, and are assumed to be modified after.  (Unless escape-analysis proves they're purely local in which case they can't be shared with another thread.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was reading [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) in the online gcc docs about the use of "memory" in the `asm` instruction.
It recommends to "_add `memory` to the list of clobbered registers_" to prevent `gcc` from keeping memory values cached in registers, but I did not see a list, so I wasn't sure the `asm/memory` (as used) would have that effect.
If it does, then obviously `volatile` can be omitted on the shared data.

Comment: Why such an old version of the gcc manual?  But anyway, my understanding is that a `"memory"` clobber looks (to the optimizer) like a non-inline function call.  (Which might use any pointer that might possibly be stored in any piece of global data, or any of its args = asm input operands.)

Comment: @LWimsey If `asm(..."memory")` is anything in intermediate compilation, how can it not be the equivalent of a function call w/o restricting attributes? IOW, if Peter Cordes was wrong **then what use would that clobber have?**

Comment: @curiousguy That is very specific for the `gcc` compiler and should be described in their manual. The `asm` statement is often used as a compiler barrier, but C++11 introduced a portable and platform independent solution.

Comment: @LWimsey *Any compiler* that supports inline asm *needs something similar to GCC clobbers* (even much coarser), or just assume that all asm clobbers everything. Otherwise asm code could simply drift away, at least in any non trivial optimization mode (or equivalently C/C++ operations would drift around inline asm.) There is no way any compiler has support for inline asm that you wouldn't be able to use reliably; inline asm is almost always used in very sensitive sections of programs.

Comment: @LWimsey "_C++11 introduced a portable and platform independent solution_" Does C++ support a substitute for the `asm("")` in most cases? I don't think so.

Comment: @curiousguy  I have no idea what direction you're going into with this. the `asm` statement as written is a compiler barrier and people used it before C++11. The new memory model provides primitives to implement the Peterson lock in a portable way. No need for these compiler dependent operations anymore.

Comment: Nobody said C++ "supports a substitute for `asm`", that's something completely different

Comment: @LWimsey Yes you can rewrite the whole function in term of atomics. My point is that there is no portable "compiler barrier" that can replace the old `asm("")`.

Comment: Yes there is, `atomic_signal_fence`, but you would not need it for a Peterson lock because atomics provide sufficiently strong ordering